# OpenIdDict: dynamic signing certificate update

Tags: openiddict

I want to implement a dynamic signing certificate update.
If I create `BackgroundService` which will inject `OpenIddictServerOptions` and update `SigningCredentials` and `TokenValidationParameters` with information about new certificate, will it be correct? Or is there a more correct way?